# why won't my d3 arc transitions work?

Tags: d3.js

I've looked at a bunch of examples of the net and can't seem to get my arc transitions to have a nice smooth animation.  I've tried two different ways to implement arcTween, both of which correctly redraw my pie charts on update, but neither of which have a smooth animation.

```
  render: (oldData, newData) ->
    return if _.compact(newData).length is 0
    @toggleWidth()
    pieData = @layout(newData)
    oldPieData = @layout(oldData)
    @arcGroup.selectAll("path").data(pieData)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("fill", (d,i) => @color(i) )
      .transition()
      .duration(250)
      .attr("d", (d) =>
        @arc()(d)
        )
      .each((d) =>
        this._current = d
      )
    @arcGroup.selectAll("path").data(pieData)
      .transition()
      .attr("fill", (d,i) => @color(i) )
      .transition()
      .duration(250)
      .attrTween("d", (d,i) =>
        @arcTween(oldPieData, d,i));
    @arcGroup.selectAll("path").data(pieData)
      .exit()
      .remove()
      .transition()
      .duration(3000)
      .attrTween("d", (d,i) =>
        @arcTween(oldPieData, d,i));
```

the comments on the arcTween method are from a different way that I was implementing this method.

```
  arcTween: (oldData, d, i) =>
    # if oldData[i]
    #   s0 = oldData[i].startAngle
    #   e0 = oldData[i].endAngle
    # else
    #   s0 = 0
    #   e0 = 0
    # i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: s0, endAngle: e0}, {startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle: d.endAngle}) 
    i = d3.interpolate(this._current, d)
    (t) =>
      b = i(t)
      @arc()(d)
```

what am I missing? thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth"? Examples like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/stephenboak/hYuPb/) look pretty smooth to me.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes, I agree that example is smooth but I can't for the life of me get mine to behave the same way, and I've been deconstructing that example for a few days to understand how these charts work.

Comment: I noticed that you have two `.transition()` statements for your update selection. You should only need one. Maybe that's it?

Comment: it didn't change anything... seems off right? i mean, if the arc's are updating correctly, then the arcTween method must be returning correctly, I don't really know what else to look at.

Comment: I think in the last line of your `arcTween` function you should pass in `b` and not `d` as an argument.

Comment: ahh, yes, very nice, thanks!

Comment: Great, I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of your `arcTween` function should read

```
@arc()(b)
```

instead of

```
@arc()(d)
```

You need to return the interpolator instead of the datum.